# Lighttpd: Restrict access from out side US

Tags: lighttpd

I am using lighttpd for hosting a php application. Is there is any way to restrict accessing the application from out side United States. I just done a quick research but didn't get a better solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this module:

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModGeoip (php example included).

Then return an error page if GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE is not what you want.